# firebase cli: firestore rules - how to specify the file to deploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

in the docs
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#use_the_firebase_cli

I know i can deploy rules using:

```
firebase deploy --only firestore:rules
```

is there a way for me to specify the location of the rules file?

Comment: for which platform? like web angular or...

Comment: i dont think you understand the question. i want to use the cli to update the rules for firestore. take a look at the docs i linked

Comment: You can't specify it on the command line.  It will take the name of the rules file from `firebase.json`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot specify the rules file location in a command-line flag, but you can set it in `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "path/to/your/firestore.rules"
  }
}
```

Comment: ohh great i'll try this. i'm assuming you meant `rules.js` correct? is there some docs abt what goes into firebase.json?

Comment: Actually for firestore it's not `rules.js` or `rules.json` since the language is neither JavaScript nor JSON.  We normally call the file `something.rules`.  The docs have more information about what is valid.

Comment: Yup, my bad on the `.json` extension.

Comment: great thanks. is there some documentation i missed abt what goes into firebase.json? would like to learn more about what i can configure here

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking everywhere for documentation of the firebase.json schema.

Comment: I have storage security rules written in the console, but don't have a storage.rules file in my project. Is one necessary? or will the rules in the console suffice? I do have firestore.rules in my project.